# Solve $\cosh x=\cos(a)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, trigonometric-series

If we have $a$ is a real number.
I know that the solution of $\cosh x=0$ is $x=2n\pi i+i\pi$.
But how we can solve $\cosh x=\cos(a)$ to find $x$?

Comment: What are $x,a$?  Not stated?  If (as is common) we therefore assume $x, a$ are real, then the only solution is $x=0, a=0$.

Answer (score 1):

$\cos(a)=\frac{\exp(ia)+\exp(-ia)}2=\cosh(ia)$

Similary, $\cos(a)=\cos(2k\pi\pm a)=\cosh(i(2k\pi\pm a))$

Comment: I want the solution of this equation, that is , the value of the variable x in this equation.